# Passing a Command Line Argument and a textfile to a program

Tags: c, command-line, command, text-files, line

I have a Read and Reverse Coding assignment where I need to pass a Textfile and a character (`-L`, or `-W`), depending on whether the operator wants the textfile returned in reverse by lines or by words. (I should also note that the assignment requires that nothing is asked of the user during the code. It must be decided which variation is wanted in the command line.)

I don't need help with the code to reverse the lines or words, but do need help with understanding how to take in character and the textfile, then use them in the code. I've tried using the parameters `(int argc, char *argv[])` on the `main`, but anytime I try to pass in just the `-L` the terminal either says `Command not found` or `clang: error: argument to '-L' is missing (expected 1 value)`

Also, when my teacher passes a textfile to a program he often uses a `>`. Can someone explain how to use this?

Ex. `program.c > hello.txt`

Then he would end up using that `.txt` in the program.

Comment: How are you trying to pass the -L ?

Comment: I guess `>` is used for redirecting. If so, `./a.out > hoge.txt` means that the standard output of `./a.out` will be not the terminal but `hoge.txt`

Comment: The command `program.c > hello.txt` looks weird. Is there C *interpreter* (or compiler is hidden in the software) to execute C *source file* directly in his environment?

Comment: Note that the `>` (and `<`) are I/O redirection operators processed by the shell — the program sees neither the operators nor the following file name.  It sounds as if you might need: `./your-program -L input-file.txt > output-file.txt` as a command line, with `-W` as an algternative.  What will your program do if neither `-L` nor `-W` is specified?  It should probably default to one or the other.  Similarly, what will you do if no file is passed?  The normal behaviour is then to read standard input.  And if many files are passed, then process each one in turn. Look up the `getopt()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
program -L < data.txt
```

or

```
program -W < data.txt
```

or

```
cat data.txt | program -L
```

The "-L" or "-W" will be in `argv[1]`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**The idea of Passing a Command Line Arguement is the following**

**Argc**: argument counter amount of "strings"(arguments) passed for execution.
Its always 1 or greater as the calling of the function is an argument.

**Argv**: argument vectors(pointers), is a pointer to each of the arguments received by the command line

**Example** of program call:

> ./myprogram -w

argc=2

argv will have two pointers to strings(char):

argv[0]= "./myprograms"

argv[1]= "-w"

**Now with your problem**

When excecuting a program via command line you have a lot of options amongst these:

1) One of these is to give the program input of a file(the file will  be passed character by character to the standard input ending with an EOF or -1 -not an ascii character-)
These can be done by the follow way

> ./program.c < hello.txt

2)Redirect the output of the program to a file

> ./program.c > hello.txt

What you are looking to do is input a file while passing an argument this can be done the following way

```
./program.c < hello.txt -L
```

**IMPORTANT**: "< hello.txt" will NOT count as an argument so for this case the case the argc and argv will be the follow

argc=2

argv[0]="./program.c"

argv[1]="-L"

Hopes this helps comment if you need anymore help or something isn't clear. Good luck with your course!!!

Comment: Thank you! This should help me. I'm going to the gym now, but will be working on the code later tonight. If I need more help I'll be sure to ask.

Comment: Quick question, how would you actually use the information from `./program.c <hello.txt -L` (Specifically the information in the .txt file.

Comment: you should pickup the char using getchar(), gets(..) and other functions to mange the stdInput check this link its well explained.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_input_output.htm